# How to save a page at a regular interval using SignalR without clicking any button?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

Can somebody explain to me how to save a .aspx page to database every minute using SignalR?
I've seen many examples but have not come across any examples that saves a page at a regular interval using SignalR without clicking any button?

Comment: Have you seen the [`window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) function? Have you tried using it?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a java-script or jquery function which saves the data to your database.

 Set the interval of the function as window.setInterval .

 you can go through following links
[Call function with setInterval in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484205/call-function-with-setinterval-in-jquery)