# setInterval() is not firing to add images at run time with fade in and fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here,I'm Trying to Fade the images one after other using setInterval() function.but it's not working here for me. can anybody please help me.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#imgMain").fadeOut().fadeIn(2000);
            var image = 1;
            function test()
            {
                switch (image)
                {
                    case "1":
                        $("#imgMain").fadeOut(2000, function () {
                            $(this).prop("src", "Images/babyshoppingbanner2.jpg")
                        }).fadeIn(2000);
                        image = 2;
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        $("#imgMain").fadeOut(2000, function () {
                            $(this).prop("src", "Images/babyshoppingbanner3.jpg")
                        }).fadeIn(2000);
                        image = 3;
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        $("#imgMain").fadeOut(2000, function () {
                            $(this).prop("src", "Images/babyshoppingbanner1.jpg")
                        }).fadeIn(2000);
                        image = 1;
                        break;
                }
            }            window.setInterval(test, 4000);
        });
```

Comment: Please copy+paste your code in the question. An image of code is next to useless

Comment: Sir @Rory McCrossan, Now can you please help to me to resolve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call function with setInterval in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484205/call-function-with-setinterval-in-jquery)

Comment: I changed the function name and called it.Though there is no  result with this @ra3iden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

case statements don't do type coercion. You have `i=1` but your case statement is looking for a `"1"`. So you need either `case 1` or `var i="1";`.

Further reading: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.11

Comment: Thank you So much sir.. it's working now....